# Trouble styling TablePagination to-from on material-table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am attempting to style the `from-to of x` rows number on a Material-Table, via

```
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
import { TablePagination, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const StyledPagination = withStyles({
    caption: {
      '&.MuiTypography-caption': {
        fontSize: '1.5rem !important'
      },
      fontSize: '1.5rem !important'
    }
  })(TablePagination)

<MaterialTable
       **Other Props Here**
        components={{
          Pagination: props => (
            <StyledPagination
              {...props}
              labelRowsPerPage={<div>{props.labelRowsPerPage}</div>}
              labelDisplayedRows={row => (
                <div>{props.labelDisplayedRows(row)}</div>
              )}
            />
          )
        }}
/>
```

I feel like those two css selectors should be redundant, but neither is working. I feel like material-table is overriding them as the computed font size is `0.75rem .MuiTypography-caption`. Have also attempted styling via the root rather than caption with no difference there either.

I have been able to style the dropdown selector for number of rows to display, which seems like the same should apply to this. Originally started with [this](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/148#issuecomment-452984812) approach, which also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving this with `MuiThemeProvider`, I dont think the normal `ThemeProvider` is working with `Material-table`

```
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
        MuiTypography: {
          caption: {
            fontSize: '1.5rem'
          }
  }
})
```

then,

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <MaterialTable />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Although, this will style anything with class MuiTypography-caption